# strange behaviour of jquery - append () is not working

Tags: jquery, json, append

this is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post("mysql_calendar/json_fail.php",
    function (data) {
      var sel = $( "#availableTime" );
      sel.empty();
      for (var i=0; i<20; i++)
        sel.append( 'val' + i + '; ' );
      sel.append ( 'test; ' ) ;
  }, "json");
  var ss = $( "#availableTime" );
  ss.empty();
  ss.append ( 'not working 1; ', 'not working 2; ', 'not working 3; ' ) ;
```

json_fail.php:

```
< ? php
echo '[]';
 ? >
```

Results of this script:
Laikas:`val0; val1; val2; val3; val4; val5; val6; val7; val8; val9; val10; val11; val12; val13; val14; val15; val16; val17; val18; val19; test;`

Why `ss.empty ()` and `ss.append` is not working? If I delete `$.post part`, it starts working. Also, if I debug it step by step with firebug, everything works as expected.

Comment: What is the version of your Jquery ??
The script runs fine for me on 1.4.4 in IE8

Answer (score 1):

what's the expected behavior?
Keep in mind that $.post is asynchronous, so first ss will be emptied, then you append 'not working1;...'.

Then the $.post callback occurs, empties it again and appends the 'val' strings.

Answer (score 0):

The post is asynchronous which causes the succss function to be called after the post has been completed.

In effect you are doing this:

```
  $.post("mysql_calendar/json_fail.php", //1) Post begins to process.
    function (data) { //5) once complete call this
      var sel = $( "#availableTime" ); //6) get ss
      sel.empty(); //7) call empty items added in 4) will be cleared.
      for (var i=0; i<20; i++) //8) append some text
        sel.append( 'val' + i + '; ' );
      sel.append ( 'test; ' ) ;
  }, "json");
  var ss = $( "#availableTime" ); //2) get ss
  ss.empty(); //3) call empty
  ss.append ( 'not working 1; ', 'not working 2; ', 'not working 3; ' ) ; //4) Append stuff
```

What do you intend as your end result?

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for your answers. After lots of googling, I found anout this asynchronous behaviour.
I created this example because $( "#availableTime" ).val('MyValue') was not working. My workaround was to define a global variable, set it to 'MyValue', and apply it to #availableTime inside function (data) block.